# Restrict content to a user role in a template file

Tags: theming, 8, users

I want to restrict a single node to anonymous users in Drupal 8. I don't want to use any module for it as its useless for single restriction as per me.

I know that I can do it with something like this.

```
{% if user.hasPermission('myPermission') %}
     //my template HTML
{% else %}
    //some login for the customer
{% endif %}
```

I don't want to restrict the content via permission, instead I want to restrict it with something like

```
{% if user.hasRole('authenticated') %}
```

Is this possible with a theme hook or do I have to use a module?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To check in twig if the user is authenticated you can use the default variable `logged_in`:

```
{% if logged_in %}
  <p>The user is authenticated".</p>
{% endif %}
```

This works because the user module provides the variable in preprocess for all templates:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_template_preprocess_default_variables_alter().
 *
 * @see user_user_login()
 * @see user_user_logout()
 */
function user_template_preprocess_default_variables_alter(&$variables) {
  $user = \Drupal::currentUser();

  $variables['user'] = clone $user;
  // Remove password and session IDs, since themes should not need nor see them.
  unset($variables['user']->pass, $variables['user']->sid, $variables['user']->ssid);

  $variables['is_admin'] = $user->hasPermission('access administration pages');
  $variables['logged_in'] = $user->isAuthenticated();
}
```

**Generic roles**

If you want to check a generic role, you can't use `hasRole()`, because this method is not available for accounts. You would have to use `getRoles()` and check if the role is in the returned array:

```
{% if 'example_role' in user.getroles  %}
  <p>The user has the role "example_role".</p>
{% endif %}
```

---

**Drupal 10.1.x**

You can use `hasRole()` now. See the change record https://www.drupal.org/node/3002289.

Comment: Since the OP is interested in finding out if the user is authenticated, this is the right answer. For a generic role, this would not work.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, you are right, this would make a more complete answer, I add the code for a generic role

Comment: the example with generic roles works like charm. to bad that "getroles" was never listed as i searched for it. thank you very much.

Comment: I didn't mean the answer was wrong, but it was the one answering the question. Now it is even better, though. I cannot up-vote it since I voted it already, but I would give it a second vote, if I could.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, didn't see the problem with the limited account interface right away. It was your hint that I digged a bit deeper where the real problem is.

Comment: The generic role example is awesome. How do I check if a user has one of x roles? My code example `{% if ('role_1' or 'role_2' or 'role_3') in user.getroles %} <p>Here is my restricted content</p> {% endif %}` does print always my restricted content.