# how to get banner image based on the role?

Tags: theming, 8, users, blocks

I want to have a banner in home page which should change according to the logged in user role.How can i achieve this?
I'm trying edit '`page--front.html.twig`'. But i'm not able to fetch logged in users role.How to check user roles inside this twig file?

Comment: How you create banner?

Comment: Different banner image, for different roles i have.when user logs in , depending on the Role of that user,banner image should change.

Comment: I am asking how you have create the banner means you are creating banner using view/block or some custom code or contributed module.

Comment: It is just a image.[<p><img src="/sites/default/files/banner/banner.jpg" /></p>] I tried adding in custom block also and tried adding in 'page--front.html.twig' also. But i didn't get proper output.

Comment: How to check user roles inside this twig file? You can do this inside of twig without php. This question is valid for all templates http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226314/restrict-node-to-user-role-in-a-template-file

Comment: Thank you.. {% if 'example_role' in user.getroles  %}
  <p>The user has the role "example_role".</p>
{% endif %}   works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you have created multiple Blocks for individual role  from Drupal admin UI.

[image]

You can restrict each block role wise.

Comment: and in Pages tab put `<front>`

Answer (score 2):

Go to your theme's folder and in your **themename.theme** file add:

```
function themename_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (\Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage()) {
    $variables['role'] = \Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles();
  }
}
```

Then in your **page--front.html.twig**, example:

```
{% if role == 'administrator' %}
  <p><img src="/sites/default/files/banner/banner.jpg"/></p>
{% elseif role == 'anonymous' %}
  <p><img src="/sites/default/files/banner/banner2.jpg"/></p>
{% endif %}
```

**Note**: If you need to be able to switch these images in the future and the person who maintains the site does not know Twig or FTP, [this is the better answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/227718/how-to-get-banner-image-based-on-the-role#answer-227723).

Comment: thanks for the answer.But {{ role }} variable i couldn't print in front twig file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the slider as a block and set the permission of that block according to required roles.

Comment: Can you add some more details to better explain how/why this answer solves the question? FYI: your answer showed up in the "low quality posts" (which puts it as risk of being deleted via moderation), hence my comment here ...